# How do I find more information about a segment of direct traffic in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, web-traffic

For the last month, one of my Websites receives on average of 50 “Direct traffic” visits daily from San Francisco, California.

My business targets the UK, so I wonder why I get this much traffic from USA. How do I get more information about this traffic in Google Analytics?

Comment: What do you want to track exactly in the direct traffic? Also, did you remove the tracking of bots? (it could be search engines that come from the USA...)

Comment: I have blocked tracking of bots long back. I am curious to find out that if I know the source & reason for this traffic, then if possible, I can do something  and get the same traffic from UK instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that your view doesn't contain the traffic from bots. To **remove the robots traffic** follow these steps:

1. Go to the "Admin" upper tab
2. Select your current property and view (or create a new view just to track non-robot traffic)
3. Choose "View Settings"
4. At "Bot Filtering", check the box : "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders"

The changes are - if I remember well - not taken into account proactively, be aware of this!

Then, if you still have this direct traffic and want to investigate it there is several ways of doing it. I usually use the "**Users Flow**" to get a global overview of what they actually do and get an idea why they are there. An other way is to use the **demographic** tab, but for low traffic website it might be inaccurate and not give a lot of answers.

In all of the reports I mentioned, you can **change the segment** from "All Users" to "Direct Traffic" (click on it and search for the right segment).

Also, consider that some people use proxies located in the US for different purposes (avoid ads on some website, get access to specific content, etc.) and this could also be the cause of this traffic.

Best!

Comment: Already I have blocked bots from GA. Thanks for the tips, I will try to use those & find the source.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also add that, if you're a large company, or there are internal people working remotely who might be affecting your traffic, you should consider including an IP filter to your view that will remove them.